# Scrollable List On Left of Div

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is in a ASP.NET web application targeting .NET 3.5 and using an AJAX `asp:UpdatePanel`.  For my page layout, I have several `div`s separating the vertical space of the page into 5 sections (header, first content, second content, third content, & footer).

[image]

The first content section contains information about the overall item the page is generated for (title and some properties).  The third section contains additional tables of information about the page's item.  And the headers and footers are...well...headers and footers.

The second content section will have 2 sub-sections, a list of images and the currently selected image.  It will work like the standard list of thumbnails in a list where you click an item and the currently selected image will be updated to the clicked thumbnail.  The currently selected image sub-section is wrapped by the AJAX `asp.UpdatePanel` and contains a title, properties table, and an image that all get updated when the selection changes.

The list can contain a large enough number of images so that when all are displayed, there would be lots of whitespace generated by pushing the selected image section bigger.

The currently selected image section will have a defined height inside the update panel that can change based on the size of the image the user wants to view (small, medium, large).

What I want is to have the list of images be sized to the height of the selected image section with a scrollbar for the overflow.

I've created a simple HTML page (below) that defines some simple content and `div`s, how do I get it to look like my desired layout (above)?  I've tried different things that I know of using floating and whatnot, but nothing seems to come out the way I want.  I would prefer not to have to specify widths or heights (except for the explicit height of the selected image div) and let things auto adjust to their contents if possible.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px; 
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

div.image {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#page-header {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

#page-footer {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.section {
}

#first-section {
}

#second-section {
}

#second-section-scroll-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    //display: inline-table;
}

ul.scroll-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li.scroll-list-item {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px; 
    text-align: center;
    //display: table;
}

#second-section-content {
    //display: inline-table;
}

#third-section {
}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page-header"><h2>My Page!<h2></div>

        <div id="first-section" class="section">
            <h1>The Item To Display</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Property 1:</th>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Property 2:</th>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div id="second-section" class="section">
            <div id="second-section-scroll-list">
                <ul class="scroll-list">
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 1</div><br/>
                        Image 1 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 2</div><br/>
                        Image 2 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 3</div><br/>
                        Image 3 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 4</div><br/>
                        Image 4 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 5</div><br/>
                        Image 5 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 6</div><br/>
                        Image 6 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 7</div><br/>
                        Image 7 Description
                    </li>
                    <li class="scroll-list-item">
                        <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 8</div><br/>
                        Image 8 Description
                    </li>
                <ul>
            </div>

            <div id="second-section-content">
                <!-- This will be wrapped in an AJAX update panel -->
                <div style="height: 800px; background-color: lightgray;">
                    <h2>Selected List Item</h2>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Property 1:</th>
                            <td>Value</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Property 2:</th>
                            <td>Value</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="image" style="height:480;width:640;">Image of Selected Item</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="third-section" class="section">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First</td>
                    <th>Second</td>
                    <th>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>1A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="page-footer">End of My Page...</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: http://blueclick.ca/projects/stackoverflow/divpanels.html?

**CSS:**

```
  html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px; 
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

div.image {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#page-header {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

#page-footer {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.section {
}

#first-section {
}

#second-section {
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;
}

#second-section-scroll-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:750px;
    float:left;
}

ul.scroll-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li.scroll-list-item {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px; 
    text-align: center;
}

#second-section-content {
margin-left:250px;
height:750px
    }

#third-section {
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="page-header"><h2>My Page!</h2></div>

    <div id="first-section" class="section">
        <h1>The Item To Display</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Property 1:</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Property 2:</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="second-section" class="section">
        <div id="second-section-scroll-list">
            <ul class="scroll-list">
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 1</div><br/>
                    Image 1 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 2</div><br/>
                    Image 2 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 3</div><br/>
                    Image 3 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 4</div><br/>
                    Image 4 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 5</div><br/>
                    Image 5 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 6</div><br/>
                    Image 6 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 7</div><br/>
                    Image 7 Description
                </li>
                <li class="scroll-list-item">
                    <div class="image" style="height: 120px; width: 160px;">Image 8</div><br/>
                    Image 8 Description
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="second-section-content">
            <!-- This will be wrapped in an AJAX update panel -->
            <div style=" height: 725px; background-color: lightgray;">
                <h2>Selected List Item</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Property 1:</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Property 2:</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="image" style="height:480;width:640;">Image of Selected Item</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>

    <div id="third-section" class="section">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>Second</th>
                <th>Third</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>1A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>2B</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="page-footer">End of My Page...</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, that's the look I'm going for - just couldn't get the scroll list to stay in its box. But I would prefer not to set heights in the CSS explicitly. Because in the UpdatePanel's content there will be buttons to resize the images used. So by default they'll start off at small res, but be able to select medium, or large. I want to be able to resize the content panel to the set size, and have the image list auto resize to the content's height. I guess I was hoping for some CSS setting or something that would take whatever the content div's height was as gold and size everything else to it.

Comment: If the image list is going to size to content's height, it should be inside content and floated left. You could also use javascript to include the resizing functionality you're talking about - even with preset heights.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I can't put it in the content sized div because I don't want the user's position in the list to get affected when they click on an image.  If it's inside the UpdatePanel, it'll refresh the list as well and scroll back to the top.

Comment: Accepting as the answer as I couldn't find a better, more dynamic solution.  Once we added the specific sizes, it works.  Not my favorite solution, but it is what it is.  Thanks.